# Allow Close Option in Taskbar When QDialog is Open above QMainWindow

Tags: qt

I have tried with setModel(false) but that is not the solution allowing that hampering other functionalities .So Now

I have one QMainwindow and QDialog pops up after clicking button on QMainwindow and I want to close the QMainWindow from Taskbar.

```
void on_btnShare_clicked()
```

{

```
auto hilightReelDlg = new HighlightReelDialog( this->highlightManager,
                                               this->soloshotAnalyzer->getNoVideoArea(),
                                               this->videoFilePaths,
                                               this->SortingOptions,
                                               this );
ui->btnShare->setEnabled(false);
if (hilightReelDlg != NULL )
{
    int NumberHilights = this->mainAppLinker->getHighlightJumper()->getActiveHighlightCount();

    ui->hilightProgressBar->setMaximum(NumberHilights);

    QObject::connect(hilightReelDlg, &HighlightReelDialog::send_Init_Progress, this, [=](int inc) 
    { 
        on_Hilight_Init_Progress(inc); 
    });
    QObject::connect(hilightReelDlg, &HighlightReelDialog::initialization_finished, this, [=]() { on_Hilight_Init_Finished(); });

    hilightReelDlg->ProcessVideoPlayers();
    //QDesktopWidget Class
    QDesktopWidget desk;
    QRect screenres = desk.screenGeometry(0);
    hilightReelDlg->setGeometry(QRect(0.10*screenres.width(), 67, 0.79*screenres.width(), 0.86*screenres.height()));
    hilightReelDlg->setModal(false);
    hilightReelDlg->show();

}
ui->btnShare->setEnabled(true);
```

}

Praveen Kumar

Comment: Provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try create QDialog with null parent insead of pointer to mainwindow. Is this case dialog will not block mainwindow. But I am sure you shouldn't do that, because in such case you will broke default behavior, which everybody used to use.

Comment: I dont have break the moduality of QDialog when pop up at button clicked , I just have to close Qmainwindow , when QDialog ie (Highlightreel) is open

Comment: Not setting a parent breaks window stacking, sometimes it makes dialogs even show up “hidden” behind the main window (seen on OS X, in particular)

Comment: @user2837508 closing window assuming closing all it's parents, in case if you have modal dialog, it's mean that you will ignore something important. It is a bad design, and you shouldn't do that.

Comment: I dont say about design but the requirement is to close mainWindow when QDialog is open and specifically from TaskBar or tray in OS X

Comment: Pls any one can help me out

Comment: @user2837508 Do you understand that closing mainwindow will cause application quit, and your dialog also will be closed. You can try `dlg->setWindowModality( Qt::NonModal );` But in such case mainwindow will not blocked by dialog

Comment: yes you are right I want to close mainwindow but i dont want to break the modality when Qdialog is PopedUp. So it seems like no other activity(Press,hover,drag etc) will affect mainwindow When I am using QDialog excluding close of Qmainwindow. And I am allowed to close mainwindow from QDialog.

Comment: @user2837508 By design it's not possible. But you can try use hack: do not set dialog as a modal, but install it as eventfilter for the mainwindow, and then filter all disared events

Comment: In OS X it working when we press Show hidden option on top left drop down , then it allow only to close option , so how to implement it is in window 7 etc